# How can i use LESS in MVC5?

Tags: less, asp.net-mvc-5

Im trying to update my project from MVC4 to MVC5. I feel like it's slower now and i can't make LESS work. I used dotless in MVC4 and it worked fine. Now dotless don't work anymore and all solutions i see in the internet are to convert LESS on the client. Can someone please show me i am wrong and show me a real solution to make LESS work on MVC5 (transforming files on the server)?

Comment: Get the "Web Essentials" -- it integrates LESS nicely with Visual Studio -- http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6

Comment: dotless still works in MVC5. Try reinstalling your package.

Comment: I will try Web Essentials, Thanks.
Shoe, can you post an example using dotless (with @import)?

Comment: dotless project on Github has been inactive for some time (https://github.com/dotless/dotless), and is missing some of the newer LESS features. Node-based solutions, like Web Essentials, are the way to go if you're using LESS in .NET.